# Query String in the URL is not allowing Media Query to get loaded in Mobile device

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a unique issue . When website is getting opened in mobile device i see Media query is not getting loaded.

When i remove the query string , then media query gets loaded

Below is the media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 a.mega_hvr_btn.hvr-shadow {
    font-size: 31px !important;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 a.mega_hvr_btn.hvr-shadow {
    font-size: 22px !important;
}
    img.aligncenter.wp-image-8.size-large.lazyloaded {
    width: 94%;
}
}
```

If URL is like this for example

https://example.com?utm_medium=1234

Then above media query does not work , when i removed "?utm_medium=1234 " and try to open url media query work.

So how to ignore query string in media query so that media query css works

I forgot to mention one thing . issue is happening when i use custom query string ... my query string is cm_s5=653 . when i used utm_source= , it is working but when i use anything other then utm , it is not working . Do i have to do something extra for custom query string

Thanks

Comment: This is likely a coincidence, or something on the server-side. Try simply refreshing the page with the query string.

Comment: i forgot to mention one thing . issue is happening when i use custom query string ... my query string is cm_s5=653 . when i used utm_source= , it is working but when i use anything other then utm , it is not working . Do i have to do something extra for custom query string

Comment: I refresh several time from various browser and mobile device same result . Not sure how custom query string affects media query

Comment: It's either something different in your HTML or cache.

Comment: It was due to one javascript which preventing css to be loaded when custom query string i used. I removed that JS and now everything fine . Thanks to all